# How can I correctly install and run gdb?

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, gdb

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get install gdb
```

but whenever I type gdb in the terminal, it inserts a new line and just doesn't load up at all.I've tried reinstalling, manually installing, still nothing. I don't have any debugging info in order to process the incapability of gdb. Below is a picture when typing "gdb".

[image]

It just hangs like in an infinite loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the output of `type gdb` ?

Comment: Output: gdb is hashed (/usr/bin/gdb)

Comment: That's the correct path. It looks like @EmployedRussian is helping you zero in on the bug - a misconfigured /usr/bin/python symlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It just hangs like in an infinite loop. Any suggestions?

You don't know whether it's waiting for something or is actually in infinite loop.

Your first steps should be:

1. Run `top` and see whether GDB process is consuming CPU or is increasing in memory and
2. Run `strace gdb` to see which (if any) system calls it is performing.

With that info, further guesses could be made.
It may also help to know which system you are on, and which version of GDB you have installed.

**Update:**

> Running strace gdb results in a infinite loop outputting: readlink(“/usr/bin/python”, “python”, 4096) = 6

So you have `/usr/bin/python` which is a symlink to *itself*.

Yes, that would cause all kinds of problems (including not being able to actually run `python` from command line).

Remove that symlink (`/usr/bin/python` is supposed to point to `python2` or `python3`).

Comment: I cannot get an output from gdb —version, so by doing apt get install gdb I can see it’s the latest (8.1-0ubuntu3.2) and Im running ubunutu 16.04. When I run gdb and in seperate terminal I can see gdb spiking cpu to 100% so it’s essentialy crashing ?

Comment: Running strace gdb results in a infinite loop outputting:       readlink(“/usr/bin/python”, “python”, 4096) = 6

Comment: Thank you so much. I did "sudo unlink /usr/bin/python" and Im able to run gdb. Thank you once again.